# How create regex with certain conditions?

Tags: java, regex

I have query for Oracle where used regex:

```
regexp_like(pe.answer_recived,'^[^0-9]*[0][^0-9]*$')
```

Now I need regex for Java with analog functionality. For Example I have this rows:

```
0
0sometext
sometext0
sometext0sometext
```

This row me need

```
sometext
00
sometext0sometext0
```

text or text with > 1 digits or only more 1 digits not need

```
String source = "0sometext" - true
String source = "00" - false
```

RESOLVE:

```
if (!pollEvent.getSms().getMessage().matches("^[^0-9]*[0][^0-9]*$")) {
                pollEvent.setStatus(2);
                InterviewDao.me().insertPollEvents(pollEvent);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by This row me need

Comment: I have List with 100 rows. I need all raws which fall under the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same regex will work in Java.  Please refer to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the `Pattern` class for details of the syntax and semantics of Java regexes.  The javadoc also includes documentation for the methods that you need to use ... and it even has an example.